areca raid controller finding temp values
Is there a way to find a temp value?  Inherited a system that was beeping couldn't figure out why, finally dawned on me to check the raid, it was an areca raid controller.  figured out how to get the cli on this old machine did a sys info:
[root@server1 x86_64]# ./cli64 sys info
The System Information
===========================================
Main Processor     : 1200MHz
CPU ICache Size    : 32KB
CPU DCache Size    : 32KB
CPU SCache Size    : 512KB
System Memory      : 2048MB/1866MHz/ECC
Firmware Version   : V1.52 2014-12-30
BOOT ROM Version   : V1.52 2014-12-30
Serial Number      : Y433CADNAR200220
Controller Name    : ARC-1883LP

But is there a command to find the temperature since the event log shows:
[root@35m-icc-server1 x86_64]# ./cli64 event info

Date-Time            Device           Event Type            Elapsed Time Errors
===============================================================================
2024-08-16 16:40:18  SW API Interface API Log In
2024-08-16 11:43:13  Ctrl CPU Temp.   Over Temp.
2024-08-16 11:40:43  CPU FAN          Failed
2024-08-16 05:30:54  Battery Module   Failed

Just not sure how to command to see what the temps are, these machines are old.  Maybe based off the controller name I can order a new one?  Can you just swap them out how would the computer boot?  probably need to dump a config from this controller to load into the new one.  I don't wanna loose data clearly.  Or maybe just a fan can be ordered and installed?
